# Print more than one value

Tags: python

C++

```cpp
std::cout << "Hello world!";

// output: Hello world!
```

Python

```py
print("Hello world!")

# output: Hello world!
```

That works. But how can I do this in Python?

```cpp
std::string name = "Robert";
std::cout << "Hello " << name << ", how are you?";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use commas to seperate arguments:

```
print("Hello ", name, ", how are you?", sep='')
```

You can also use the f string formatter:

```
print(f"Hello {name}, how are you?")
```

or also with `str.format()`:

```
print("Hello {}, how are you?".format(name))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:-

```
name = 'Robert'
print(f'Hello {name}, how are you?')
OR
print('Hello ', name, ', how are you?', sep='')
```

Output:-

```
Hello Robert, how are you?
```

Answer (score -1):

```
name = 'Robert'
print('Hello ',  name,', how are you?',sep = '')
```

sep - separator parameter, which will eliminate the space between name and comma.